# Naming conventions in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it good to have the function name same as the event listeners?

Example:

```
function onClick: function(event){
//body
}

<div class="example" onClick={this.onClick} />
```

Comment: This is IMO bad practice. Too often you run into situations like  `<input onChange={this.onChange} />` and then you realise it should be `onInput` instead.

This issue goes to same category as naming elements / components by their position or colour (e.g. `sidebar-left`, `navigation-blue`) and then design ends up moving sidebar to right or turn navigation to green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter what coding language you use, the name of a function should be as informative as possible. A function name like **onClick** does not describe what the function does. If you want to call this function from another place the name **onClick** would not help you understand the purpose of the function. You would have to view the code to understand it.

It would be better to be more descriptive and call it something like this :

1. **sendPrivateMessage()**
2. **clientAddress**
3. **doSomething()**

The name you choose depends on what this function does.

If you are interested in "clean code standards" I think this is the best book about clean coding and naming standards : [clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)